# Get decibels of 1 second of audio file using naudio

Tags: c#, .net, naudio

I wanna to calculate decibels of 1 second of any .wav file using naudio. This is my code:

```
WaveFileReader reader = new WaveFileReader(@"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\result.wav");
int bytesPerMillisecond = reader.WaveFormat.AverageBytesPerSecond / 1000;            
//byte[] buffer = new byte[reader.Length];
//int read = reader.Read(buffer, 0, (int)reader.Length);
TimeSpan time = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);

int bytesPerSecond = (int)time.TotalMilliseconds * bytesPerMillisecond;
byte[] oneSecondBuffer = new byte[bytesPerSecond];
int read = reader.Read(oneSecondBuffer, 0, bytesPerSecond);

short sample16Bit = BitConverter.ToInt16(oneSecondBuffer, 1);
double volume = Math.Abs(sample16Bit / 32768.0);
double decibels = 20 * Math.Log10(volume);
```

This line:

```
short sample16Bit = BitConverter.ToInt16(oneSecondBuffer, 1);
```

returns 0. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In the Title of your question please clarify the problematic part, which is BitConverter.ToInt16(oneSecondBuffer, 1) line returning 0. Calculating decibels is immaterial because the real issue happened before. Best regards,

Comment: @Alexander Tried different wavs ? BitConverter.ToInt16 can return 0, e.g. if the byte array element is 00-00

Answer (score 3):

I've resolved this task in another way. This is a piece of code, which may help other people:

```cs
var silenceDict = new Dictionary<int, bool>();
using (NAudio.Wave.AudioFileReader wave = new NAudio.Wave.AudioFileReader(filePath))
{
    var samplesPerSecond = wave.WaveFormat.SampleRate * wave.WaveFormat.Channels;
    var readBuffer = new float[samplesPerSecond];
    int samplesRead;
    int i = 1;
    do
    {
        samplesRead = wave.Read(readBuffer, 0, samplesPerSecond);
        if (samplesRead == 0) break;
        var max = readBuffer.Take(samplesRead).Max();

        if ((int)(max * 100) != 0)
            silenceDict.Add(i, false);
        else
            silenceDict.Add(i, true);

        i++;
    } while (samplesRead > 0);
}
```